# extracting dataframe cell value in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

I have a Dataframe as below that contains string and NaN value

I'm creating a for loop to loop through each value. How do I call/extract just the value of the cell in the loop.

```
Example : 
for idx in df.index:
    for i in range(14):
          x = first row, "Sentence" column which is equal to the string "If your genetic..."
              (idx is 1 and i is 0)
          y = first row, "First" column which is equal to "10|||the"
              (idx is 1 and i is 1)

DataFrame : 

    Sentence    First   Second  Third   Fourth  Fifth   Sixth   Seventh Eighth  Nineth  tenth   eleventh    twelveth    thirteen
S                                                       
1   If your genetic...  10|||the    26|||will   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

Loop : 
for idx in df.index:
    for i in range(14):
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem https://xyproblem.info/. What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to iterate through each i,j value of the data frame, you can do something like this:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        print(df.iloc[i, j])
```